# Python Lettuce BDD feature file will not run - How do i run it

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bdd

I have just started to learn BDD as I want to convert my Python Webdriver regression test cases to use BDD.  I want to gain BDD as this is widely used in the industry now.

I am following a simple calculator tutorial with a feature and steps file.
When i run the feature file from the Python console i get the following error:
To run it from PyCharm i select View -> Tool Windows -> I select Python Console.
Python Console window opens I then type in PythonBDD/tests/features/calculator_feature.feature

```
        >> PythonBDD/tests/features/calculator_feature.feature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'PythonBDD' is not defined
>>> tests/features/calculator_feature.feature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tests' is not defined
>>> $ lettuce
  File "<input>", line 1
    $ lettuce
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> $lettuce
  File "<input>", line 1
    $lettuce
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> cd pythonbdd
  File "<input>", line 1
    cd pythonbdd
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> calculator_feature.feature$ lettuce
  File "<input>", line 1
    calculator_feature.feature$ lettuce
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> calculator_feature.feature lettuce
  File "<input>", line 1
    calculator_feature.feature lettuce
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> calculator_feature.feature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'calculator_feature' is not defined
>>> lettuce calculator_feature.feature
  File "<input>", line 1
    lettuce calculator_feature.feature
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> PythonBDD/tests/features/calculator_feature.feature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'PythonBDD' is not defined
```

How do i run the feature file?

My code tree structure is as follows:

```
PythonBDD
    -- app
        --_init_.py
        -- calculator.py
    -- tests
        -- features
            -- calculator_feature.features
            -- calculator_steps.py
```

calculator_steps.py

```
from lettuce import *
from nose.tools import assert_equals
from app.calculator import Calculator


@step(u'I am using the calculator')
def select_calc(step):
    print ('Attempting to use calculator...')
    world.calc = Calculator()


@step(u'I input "([^"]*)" add "([^"]*)"')
def given_i_input_group1_add_group1(step, x, y):
    world.result = world.calc.add(int(x), int(y))


@step(u'I should see "([^"]+)"')
def result(step, expected_result):
    actual_result = world.result
    assert_equals(int(expected_result), actual_result)
```

calculator_feature.feature

```
Feature: As a writer for NetTuts
  I wish to demonstrate
  How easy writing Acceptance Tests
  In Python really is.

  Background:
    Given I am using the calculator

  Scenario: Calculate 2 plus 2 on our calculator
    Given I input "2" add "2"
    Then I should see "4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run `lettuce` in your tests directory.

Also note the typo in the `calculator_feature.features` filename in your tree structure.

Note that `PyCharm` has [built-in support](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-behavior-driven-development-in-pycharm/) for both `Behave` and `Lettuce` popular BDD frameworks.